# Show results in Group wise MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

What i am trying is that i have a lottery table. I have to show the purchase lottires of the user. Each user purchase pack of 10, it may be more or less, if it increase then it consider as other pack. Now i have to show the results date wise and each pack with its own blocks here is the example image of current results which i am getting

[image]

What i want is that eache purrchase must show in there own blocks like this
with section_id at the end
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTDyo.png)

now currently if i purchase 8 ticket then by 5 and then 6, they must be display in each separate box, not in one box. Am also using a unique id for each purchase so that they can be group in one block, here is my code and table structure

```
<?php 

        $sql        = "SELECT * FROM users_lottery WHERE user_id  = '".$userid."' ORDER BY dt ASC ";
        $run        = $db->Execute($sql);
        $cn         = 1;
        $day_check  = '';
        $i          = 1;
        if($run -> EOF){?>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 playedHeading">No game have finnish to show here jet. good luck</div>
        </div>
        <?php 
        } 
         while(!$run -> EOF){
            $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($run->fields("dt")));   
            if ($date != $day_check) {
                if($cn != 1){

                    $i=11;
                    if($i == 11){
                        echo '</div>';
                        $i=1;
                    }
                }
                echo '<div class="col-md-12"><h2>'.date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)).'</h2></div> <br clear="all" />';

            }
            if($i == 11){
                echo '</div>';
                $i=1;
            }
            if($i == 1){
                echo '<div class="col-md-4 box_div '.$i.'">';
            }
        ?>
        <?php //if ($cn % 5 == 0) { ?>

          <div class="blocks">
            <div class="">
                <?=$i?>:&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <?=$run->fields("lottery_row_1");?>
              -
              <?=$run->fields("lottery_row_2");?>
              -
              <?=$run->fields("lottery_row_3");?>
              -
              <?=$run->fields("lottery_row_4");?>
              -
              <?=$run->fields("lottery_row_5");?>
              -
              <?=$run->fields("lottery_row_6");?>
              -
              <?=$run->fields("lottery_row_7");?>
            </div>

          </div>

        <?php

        if ($date != $day_check) {

            $i=1;
        } 
        $day_check = $date;
        $run->MoveNext();  $cn++; $i++;} $run->Close();?>
```

Table Structure

[image]

Comment: _"here is my code and table structure"_ - So what do you get when you run that code?

Comment: That green image, this is the results, now i want that separate each purchase into further blocks. 2018-03-07 have more then 5 purchase but they are showing in blocks of 10.

Comment: You should update your question to clarify that the first image is what you're currently getting and add an example of what you actually want. It's not that obvious from the description.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i have added the other image of required results which i want

Comment: Split the lottery rows into a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

You would normally have a detail table. It might look like this (although the second column seems unnecessary to me)...

```
main_table_id lottery_row number
            3           1     57
            3           2     82
            3           3     64
            3           4     64 <-- odd that this value appears twice
            3           5     99
            3           6     11
            3           7     28
```